How to generate a turtle format file of rdf-star using rdflib?
See example 19 of w3 rdf1.2 specification:
PREFIX :    <http://www.example.org/>
:employee38 :familyName "Smith" .
<< :employee38 :jobTitle "Assistant Designer" >> :accordingTo :employee22 .

I want to use rdflib to generate a turtle file like this, However, the following code generates incorrect file content:
from rdflib import Graph, Namespace, Literal, BNode
from rdflib.namespace import RDF, RDFS
ns = Namespace("http://www.example.org/")
g = Graph()
g.add((ns["employee38"], ns["familyName"], Literal("Smith")))
nested_triple = BNode()
g.add((nested_triple, RDF.type, RDF["Statement"]))
g.add((nested_triple, RDF["subject"], ns["employee38"]))
g.add((nested_triple, RDF["predicate"], ns["jobTitle"]))
g.add((nested_triple, RDF["object"], Literal("Assistant Designer")))
g.add((nested_triple, ns["accordingTo"], ns["employee22"]))
g.serialize(destination="output.ttl", format="turtle")

How should I generate this turtle file correctly? Thanks in advance for any help！

you're link is referring to a working draft of RDF 1.2 . Neither is this already a standard nor supported by all tools. For rdflib there is a fork resp. PR which you'd need, see discussion here: https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/discussions/1554 - and those are probably already older than the current spec of RDF Star - long story short, but out of the box, the latest release of rdflib does not support RDF star

Yes, I have tried and it is true that rdflib currently does not support read and write operations for "quoted triple"
